# How to get current swipe direction in action in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to use ViewPager for showing different views.

Below is code I am using to check whether swiping is left or right

```
    myPager.setOnTouchListener(new ViewPager.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();

            switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mStartDragX = x;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (event.getX() > mStartDragX ) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"SWIPING RIGHT");
                } else if (event.getX() < mStartDragX) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"SWIPING LEFT");
                }
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

So when I start to swipe from right to left or right to left its showing me correct log message.

But if I started to swipe from right to left and at the same time again if start to swipe from left to right, how can I identify whether currently swiping in which direction?

Can anyone please help ?

Thanks

Comment: that means first some distance you swiped left to right then from that position you again swiped back right??

Comment: correct... like that only

Comment: ok..wait i will post..

Comment: posted.. change your code like that and let me know

Comment: ok... I will try and let you know.. thnks

Answer (score 2):

Then do somethink like this..

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    if (event.getX() > mStartDragX) {
            Log.i(TAG, "SWIPING RIGHT");
            mStartDragX = event.getX();
        } else if (event.getX() < mStartDragX) {
            Log.i(TAG, "SWIPING LEFT");
            mStartDragX = event.getX();
        }
```

Here i am saving the current position again to old position so whenever the swiped back it will give the correct result..