# ViewPager halfway scrolled callback

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager and above that ViewPager is a TextView. When I change page in the ViewPager, the TextView should update its text based on the content of the new page.

I call the setText method in the onPageSelected method of my ViewPager's OnPageChangeListener. It works great!

Now I want to add a little animation. While swiping, the text should fade out, and when it's halfway, it should fade back, with the new text. I managed to do the alpha animation for the text. But, the text is changing **after** the text has faded back. I want to change the text once the text is invisible (halfway the scrolling).

Any help? Here is my code:

```
weekPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int index) {
            //update the text
            weekText.setText(DateTimeUtils.getWeekDescription(index));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float ratio, int arg2) {
            //do the alpha animation
            weekText.setAlpha(Math.abs(2f * (ratio - .5f)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you not just add an animation to the whole ViewPager instead? http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Well, it's actually not really an animation, it's actually adjusting the alpha according to the sliding progress.

Comment: That is what I believe you could do on the entire ViewPager, instead of handling each individual view

Comment: I don't think you understand the question, please read it again.

Comment: look how they animate the strip https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/X8fg63wK6S8

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

In your Activity declare these vars

```
private int mIndex = 0;
private int lastIndex = 0;
private float mStartDragX = 0;
```

Then

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float ratio, int arg2) {
        //do the alpha animation
        float alpha = 2f * (ratio - .5f);
        weekText.setAlpha(Math.abs(alpha));

        //If the text hasn't been set and ratio is at least halfway from 0 -> 1
        // alpha should be near 0, ideally exactly 0
        if((mIndex != lastIndex) && (alpha >= 0))
        {
           weekText.setText(DateTimeUtils.getWeekDescription(mIndex));
           lastIndex = mIndex;
        }
}
```

EDIT:
In order to properly set mIndex you'll need to do a little extra work.

From this question [How to get current swipe direction in action in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680978/how-to-get-current-swipe-direction-in-action-in-viewpager)

It seems one way is an onTouchListener of the ViewPager, I'm not sure if this will work perfectly but it is worth trying.

```
myPager.setOnTouchListener(new ViewPager.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();

        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mStartDragX = x;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (event.getX() > mStartDragX )
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"SWIPING RIGHT - Selecting page to the left");
                if(mIndex == lastIndex)
                   mIndex--;
            } else if (event.getX() < mStartDragX)
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"SWIPING LEFT - Selecting page to the right");
                if(mIndex == lastIndex)
                   mIndex++;
            }
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you have a tab bar you'll also have to set mIndex when the user presses those buttons.

Comment: Not correct. It does call the setText method at the right time, but the mIndex is still the old value, so the text still doesn't change.

Comment: ah this is because onPageSelected happens after the scroll. arg0 seems to be the position of the old page. Let me make an edit

Comment: @MarkBuikema try the new code with the edit, basically the goal is to set mIndex before the setText call, if this doesn't work you'll have to figure out how to track the index yourself and set it before you select the viewpager's page. You might have to reverse the arg2 comparisons if pages to the right have a negative pixel offset.

Comment: It works perfectly when I scroll to the right, but when I scroll to the left the text changes after releasing my finger.

Comment: Appears that the pixels (arg2) are never negative and the index (arg0) is always the index of the leftmost visible page.

Comment: @MarkBuikema that's unfortunate I was hoping that would work. I've edited my answer to show an alternative. You basically need to intercept any events that can cause the page to change before it actually does and set mIndex there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61135/discussion-between-dave-s-and-mark-buikema).